# DataGridView shifts row on update

Tags: c#, datagridview

Sometimes when I update a row in a DataGridView a shift occurs in the row like this:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/eb932776d2.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/eb932776d2.jpg)

Look at the row in the middle and notice how three of the columns are drawn incorrectly.  Once this happens, even a refresh doesn't seem to fix the problem.  The problem does go away when any of the data in the row gets changed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what can be causing that, but have you tried calling Invalidate()?

You can try this.gridView1.Invalidate() or this.InvalidateRow(rowIndex).